# mod_rewrite: Exact URL not matching but matches non exact

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having issues while using mod_rewrite in an .htaccess file to redirect to another domain.

Here's what I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.somedomain.com/events_detail/an-event [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://otherdomain.com/directory/8559 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.somedomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://otherdomain.com/directory [L,R=301,NC]
```

For some reason `www.somedomain.com/events_detail/an-event` I get redirected to `http://otherdomain.com/directory` instead of `http://otherdomain.com/directory/8559`

When testing out my .htaccess on a tester, it indicates that it does not match the first condition but matches the second. I have tried removing the L option, removing the forward ^ without success.

Thank you

Comment: Use %{REQUEST_URI} to match against a pathname in url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.somedomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /an-Event [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://otherdomain.com/directory/8559 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.somedomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://otherdomain.com/directory [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I didn't understand that `HTTP_HOST` was only the hostname and that I needed an extra condition for the request. However what is the difference between `THE_REQUEST` and `REQUEST_URI` (both work fine for me)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, **HTTP_HOST** contains only the host name (e.g. *www.somedomain.com*), and not the complete url. Have you tried using **REQUEST_URI** or **SCRIPT_FILENAME** instead?